# Binary Bit Extraction: How to Isolate Digits from a Whole Number in R

Tags: r, binary

New to the stackoverflow here!

I hope you are all doing well. I am currently working on a dota2 data anaylst project for uni assignment and have encountered a problem that I am unable to solve on my own. I would appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide.

Problem Description:
How do you extract digits from a binary number? For example, there's a column filled with strings like '00110011' , and now I want to get the 6th digit and 7th digit from all of them, then create 2 new columns in the original csv file.

Thank you for your time and help in advance! Hope everyone who see this post have a great day!

This is what I tried to get all the 8 digits, but I don't think it's a good solution and I'm expecting a better one, I still have no idea on how to put the digits into new columns and only extract 6th and 7th digit.

```
data <- '00111111'
 
#transfer to integer first
Integer <- strtoi(data, base=2)
 
bits <- numeric(8)
For(I in 1:8){
    Bits[i] <- (data%/% (2^(i-1))) %% 2
}
 
Bits
```

Comment: Are you looking for `substr('00111111', 6, 7)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Tidyverse is an option, I would consider something like this for feature extraction:

```r
df <- data.frame(data = "00111111")

df <- df |>
  dplyr::mutate(b = strsplit(data, "")) |>
  tidyr::unnest_wider(b, names_sep = ".")
df
#> # A tibble: 1 × 9
#>   data     b.1   b.2   b.3   b.4   b.5   b.6   b.7   b.8  
#>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 00111111 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1

# to select a subset of clomns and/or rename:
df |>
  dplyr::select(data, middle_melee = b.6, top_ranged = b.7)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   data     middle_melee top_ranged
#>   <chr>    <chr>        <chr>     
#> 1 00111111 1            1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works! Cheers!

Comment: Is the result reuseable? I mean
```
df_dire_barracks <- data.frame(data = barracks$dota.barracks_status_dire)
df_dire_barracks |>
  dplyr::mutate(b = strsplit(data, "")) |>
  tidyr::unnest_wider(b, names_sep = ".")
```
and I got the result I want, now I want to rename the column and delete the column I don't want, should I do it on df_dire_barracks?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. For renaming and dropping unused columns I'd use a single `select() ` as  final step in that dplyr pipeline. In edit the pipeline was split, but only to show the result from `unnest_wider()`.

Comment: Fixed it! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If with 6th and 7th `substring` you mean this,

```
substr('00111111', 6, 7)
# [1] "11"
```

to get the two columns you can do

```
data.frame(df, sapply(6:7, \(i) substr(df$X, i, i)))
#           X X1 X2
# 1  11011110  1  1
# 2  11011001  0  0
# 3  10011011  0  1
# 4  01010111  1  1
# 5  01010011  0  1
# 6  00010111  1  1
# 7  11000101  1  0
# 8  10011111  1  1
# 9  10011000  0  0
# 10 00010010  0  1
```

Assuming you know already how to `df <- read.csv('foo.csv')`.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(X=replicate(10, paste(rbinom(8, 1, .5), collapse='')))
```

Comment: What if I want to go from the first digit to the sixth digit?
and when I try to use substr, R shows 'Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default'

Comment: @kenhood `substr('00111111', start=1, stop=6)`. No clue why you get the error.

Comment: @kenhood `data.frame(df, sapply(c(1, 6), \(i) substr(df$X, i, i)))` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit(data, "")` to convert a string to a vector of characters, so your solution could look something like this:

```r
data <- c('00111111', '01001101', '01010100')

strsplit(data, "") |>
  sapply(function(x) as.numeric(x[7:8])) |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("seventh", "eighth"))
#>   seventh eighth
#> 1       1      1
#> 2       0      1
#> 3       0      0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `substr` solution offered by @jay.sf is the most performant of `strsplit` and a couple other options I thought of:

```
library(data.table)

bench::mark(
  tstrsplit = dt[,c("x6", "x7") := tstrsplit(x, "", keep = 6:7)],
  substr = dt[,c("x6", "x7") := lapply(6:7, \(i) substr(x, i, i))],
  strsplit = dt[,c("x6", "x7") := transpose(lapply(strsplit(x, ""), `[`, 6:7))],
  strtoi = dt[,c("x6", "x7") := as.data.table(outer(strtoi(dt$x, 2), 2^(8 - 6:7), "%/%")%%2)]
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 tstrsplit    4.32ms   4.91ms      197.    1.47MB     8.75
#> 2 substr       1.29ms   1.42ms      678.  172.73KB     4.13
#> 3 strsplit     8.43ms   8.76ms      106.  485.41KB    11.8 
#> 4 strtoi       2.55ms    2.8ms      346. 1014.37KB     4.16
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.table(
  x = do.call(paste0, as.data.frame(matrix(runif(8e4)%/%0.5, 1e4, 8)))
)
```